# Почему if возвращает false если условие выполняется

Tags: javascript

Почему if возвращает false если условие выполняется, ошибок в условии и нигде, не наблюдается

```
function convenience_UI(
        selector, // селектор
        fonts_arr, // массив верных шрифтов 
        tooltips_neccesary, // должны ли иметь поля подсказки (boolean)
        free_space_arr, // свободное место, по x и y (массив[x,y])
        btn_size_arr // правильный размер кнопок (массив[width,height]) (всё в пикселях)
    ) {
    var btn = el_sa(selector);
    for(var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++)
    {
      if(btn[i].style.width === btn_size_arr[0] && btn[i].style.height === btn_size_arr[1])
      {
        console.log("the correct size of the button № "+i+" : " + btn[i]);
      } else
      {
        console.log("the wrong size of the button № "+i+" : " + btn[i]);
      }
    }
 }

 convenience_UI("div", 1, 1, 1, [100, 100]);
```

```
function el_s(selector) { 
    return document.querySelector(selector); 
}
function el_sa(selector) { 
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector); 
}
```

```
div:first-child
{
  width: 100;
  height: 100;
}
```

```
  <div>0</div>
  <div>1</div>
```

Comment: что это за el_sa(selector) ?

Comment: function el_s(selector)
 {
   return document.querySelector(selector);
 }

 function el_sa(selector)
 {
   return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
 }

Comment: Условие не выполняется, по крайней мере у меня, с чего вы вдруг решили что оно выполняется?

Comment: Если if возвращает false, значит условие не выполняется. Народная мудрость.

Comment: 1) height и width - это строки, поэтому если в массиве лежат числа сравнение с помощью `===` всегда даст false. 2) в свойстве style элемента находится только то, что есть непосредственно в **атрибуте** style

Comment: 3) в CSS единицы измерения обязательны для ненулевых значений